# The method getKey(String, String) is undefined for the type CryptoUtils

Tags: java, class, normalization

Helo
any help can be good for me.
I have to convert a jason to some kind of string by a java class. But it has 2 errors in line 84, 90 method getkey.
Inside the flatMap function

```
package normjsn;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import java.text.Collator;
import java.util.*;



public class CryptoUtils {
    private final static ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    public static byte[] hexStringToByteArray(String s) {
        int len = s.length();
        byte[] data = new byte[len / 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 2) {
            data[i / 2] = (byte) ((Character.digit(s.charAt(i), 16) << 4) + Character.digit(s.charAt(i + 1), 16));
        }
        return data;
    }
    
    
    
    public static String normalJson(Object object, Map<String, Object> header) {
        if (object == null && header == null) return null;

        Map<String, Object> map = null;
        if (object != null) {
            if (object instanceof String) {
                try {
                    object = mapper.readValue((String) object, Object.class);
                } 
                catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage());
                }
            }
            if (object instanceof Collection) {
                /// @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")  /// Skip non generic var s warning
                PacketsWrapper packetsWrapper = new PacketsWrapper((Collection) object);
                map = mapper.convertValue(packetsWrapper, Map.class);
            } else {
                map = mapper.convertValue(object, Map.class);
            }
        }
        if (map == null && header != null) {
            map = header;
        }
        if (map != null && header != null) {
            for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : header.entrySet()) {
                map.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
            }   
        }

        Map<String, Object> result = new HashMap<>();
        flatMap(result, null, map);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        List<String> keys = new ArrayList<>(result.keySet());
        Collections.sort(keys, Collator.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH));
        for (String key : keys) {
            String textValue;
            Object value = result.get(key);
            if (value != null) {
                textValue = value.toString();
                if (textValue == null || textValue.equals("")) {
                    textValue = "#";
                } else {
                    textValue = textValue.replaceAll("#", "##");
                }
            } else {
                textValue = "#";
            }
            sb.append(textValue).append('#');
        }
        return sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length() - 1).toString();
    }
    
    
    
    private static void flatMap(Map<String, Object> result, String rootKey, Object input) {
            if (input instanceof Collection) {
                Collection list = (Collection) input;
                int i = 0;
                for (Object e : list) {
                    String key = getKey(rootKey, "E" + i++);
                    flatMap(result, key, e);
                }
            } else if (input instanceof Map) {
                Map<String, Object> map = (Map) input;
                for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {
                    flatMap(result, getKey(rootKey, entry.getKey()), entry.getValue());
                }
            } else {
                result.put(rootKey, input);
            }
    }
    
    
    
    
    
    private static class PacketsWrapper {
        private Collection packets;
        public PacketsWrapper() {}
        public PacketsWrapper(Collection packets) {
            this.packets = packets;
        }
        public Collection getPackets() {
            return packets;
        }
        public void setPackets(Collection packets) {
            this.packets = packets;
        }
    }
    
    
    
}
```

More about me: have you heard of vb6? yeah, I am a dinosaur age programmer. Recently I have to connect to government tax API and they have gave a non-useful document guide and the above class is suggested in the document.
Unfortunately there is no support, and it's about 1 month I am working on it but because of lack of info and support I am still in the first line :))))

Comment: hello and welcome to StackOverflow. The error you are facing is very basic and needs also very basic Java knowledge. I am afraid if you do not have this knowledge, even after you fix this one, you will face another simple error. If you are really planning to work with Java it would be usefull to: 1) get an IDE which helps you to fix  this basic errors (eg IntelliJIdea), 2) Read some basic concepts about Java.  The error which you encounter simply says that in your class you have not defined the getKey(..) method. Maybe you have not copied everything from the example?

Comment: There is no method `getKey` in your class. Consequently, you cannot call it. You can only call methods that exist